# @font-face works locally on IE10, but not on the server

Tags: css, font-face

I checked and the font files are on the server:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DroidSerifRegular';
    src: url('fontface/DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fontface/DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fontface/DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fontface/DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fontface/DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.svg#DroidSerifRegular') format('svg');
    src: local('☺'),
         url('fontface/DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DroidSerifItalic';
    src: url('fontface/DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fontface/DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fontface/DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fontface/DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fontface/DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.svg#DroidSerifItalic') format('svg');
    src: local('☺'),
         url('fontface/DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

EDIT: What's weird is that the font is showing correctly in IE8, but not IE9 or IE10.

I also tried:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DroidSerifRegular';
    src: local('☺'),
         url('http://www.mysite.ca/themes/mysite/fontface/DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://www.mysite.ca/themes/mysite/fontface/DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://www.mysite.ca/themes/mysite/fontface/DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://www.mysite.ca/themes/mysite/fontface/DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.svg#DroidSerifRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And my .htaccess:

```
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Another EDIT:

I just checked in IE and I am getting this message:

```
CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable
```

Comment: sometimes the url must take the entire path to the file.

Comment: Good point. I just tried that but it's still not working...it's not defaulting to a web font...it just looks very strange and skinny and aliased.

Comment: What does your server's .htaccess look like (i'm assuming you are on apache).

Comment: I vaguely remember having a similar problem .  And if I remember correctly, for me, there was actualy something wrong with the font file. I had to ask the font provider (in my case it was myfonts.com) to re-generate the font file for me.

Comment: The weird thing is it works before I upload the file to the server (meaning, locally on my computer)...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove this part:

```
local('☺')
```

Or add the rest of fonts in this part too, like

```
src: local('☺'),
url('GraublauWeb.woff') format('woff'), url('GraublauWeb.ttf') format('truetype');
```

And can you confirm you have all these fonts on server too?

---

Try to use this tool to create yout fonts:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Select the 'expert' control option and change from 'EOT Compressed' to 'EOT Lite'

Comment: I have all the fonts (typed in each URL to check)

Comment: Try to use this tool to create yout fonts:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Did you try to selected the 'expert' control option and change from 'EOT Compressed' to 'EOT Lite' ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on an IIS-Server and finally realized, that I had to add the mime-type "woff" to the ISS, so that the file is delivered. It seemed like the other browsers supportet other filetypes, so that they took others when they could not access the woff, but ie11 needed the woff.

Answer (score 0):

IIS-Server versions prior to 8 seem to not have the mime-type "woff" added by default. Add it to the list (server > your site > mime-types) and you should be fine. This at least solved the CSS3114 error in IE 11 for me. FF and Chrome never had a problem with it, as they seem to be less restrictive in this point.