# fonts not rendering in ie 10 or 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face

My site: http://arethebaronsplaying.com/

isn't rendering fonts correctly in IE 10 or IE 11. Here's my css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Mono Social Icons Font';
src: asset_url('fonts/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot');
src: asset_url('fonts/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     asset_url('fonts/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.woff') format('woff'),
     asset_url('fonts/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.ttf') format('truetype'),
     asset_url('fonts/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.svg#MonoSocialIconsFont') format('svg');
src: asset_url('fonts/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'hamilton18';
  src: asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-718-webfont.eot');
  src: asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-718-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-718-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
   asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-718-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
   asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-718-webfont.svg#MonoSocialIconsFont') format('svg');
  src: asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-718-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Everything looks great in chrome/safari/firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using

Comment: I tested in IE 10 and IE 11, both look terrible.

Comment: I would recommend just using a tool such as http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator.

Comment: Check the console in IE and make sure everything is loaded correctly and no 404s.

Comment: Any other theories, I already have the `eot?#iefix` in the font settings?

Comment: I don't have a PC so not sure how much I can help.  Just make sure the font is valid and that IE can see the font.  So view the source and make sure the font is actually there

Comment: Are your font the first thing in the css file?  No idea if that will help but load those first as they are the largest assets

Comment: http://arethebaronsplaying.com/assets/fonts/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot gives me 404

Comment: I looked at this and it talked about checking permissions.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157516/font-face-works-locally-on-ie10-but-not-on-the-server?rq=1
I would check your permissions.

Comment: interesting. I'm calling it like so `src: asset_url('fonts/hamilton_wood_type_foundry_-_hwtunitgothic-718-webfont.eot');` which rails syntax. Perhaps I have to call the ie font differently?

Comment: Not quite sure.  Like I said, check IE for errors and that should give you a better idea.

Comment: The similar question asked over here, please check:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065362/ie9-blocks-download-of-cross-origin-web-font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the console in IE of your website, there appear following error -

"CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable."

On web, these are the two links which talk about this issue and common solution:
https://github.com/tapquo/lungo.icon/issues/1
and
http://codecanyon.net/forums/thread/css3114-fontface-failed-opentype-embedding-permission-check-permission-must-be-installable/78963

common solution link:
http://carnage-melon.tom7.org/embed/

However the talked tool seems available only for older version of windows and not for latest version of windows.

Comment: This looks promising, thank you very much. Anyway to fix this issue on a mac?

Comment: Your welcome :), please upvote or accept  as per your consideration if this answer helped in your issue.

Comment: Last question...do you know how I could go about fixing this on a mac?

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem just add `-ms-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1;` to your css

for example:

```
.social .icon {
  -ms-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1;
  font-family:'Mono Social Icons Font';
  -webkit-text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
  -moz-text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
  -ms-text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
  -o-text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
  text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  -ms-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  -o-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  font-smoothing:antialiased;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, the font was loading but the actual icon was not being rendered.